# cannot get value with callback - javascript

Tags: javascript

The other answer seems to suggest this should work (so not a duplicate):

I am trying to be able to use the result object outside of the function. I have used a callback, however I am still having problems.

```
exports.getArray = function(query, callback) {
    connection.query('SELECT ' + query + ' FROM table', function(err, result) {
        if (!err) {
            var array = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                array.push({
                    id: result[i].id,
                });
            }
            callback(array);
            console.log('Retrieved Data');
        } else
            console.log('Error while retrieving data.');
    });
}
```

In another file

```
var data = [];
database.getArray('*', function(result) {
    //  console.log(result); //works
    data.concat(result); //need the result value 
});

console.log(data); // Outputs []
```

log:

```
[{ 
    id: 71,
    author: 'catnip' 
 }, { 
    id: 78,
    author: 'cup49'
}]
```

Comment: The line that says `console.log(data); // Outputs []` runs immediately, it does not wait for the callback function

Comment: change this  `data.concat(result);` to `data = result;`

Comment: _“The other answer seems to suggest this should work (so not a duplicate)”_ — what other answer are you talking about?

Comment: move your `console.log(data);` line of code right below `data.concat(result);` and also wait for a moment for the callback to execute.

Comment: You've posted the same question/code [as your last now-deleted question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36522613/getting-a-value-from-a-callback-javascript) which was put on hold because the question had been answered before. Did you read the linked post? What do you hope to gain from asking the question again?

Comment: Thanks mparnisari I will look at that. I did read the other post and it said to do what I am already doing. I still needed an answer so I deleted the old post. data = result; makes no difference.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
data = result;
```

or

```
data = data.concat(result);
```

The `concat` method returns a new array. It does not modify the array on which it is being called.

Comment: This is not the problem.

Comment: Move `console.log(data);` inside your callback function, as mparnisari suggested above, so that it only executes after you get your result

Comment: But I need to use data outside the callback, and not just print it. How can I get it to sync so it is usable?

Comment: Can you move other work that relies on data inside the callback? An alternative is you can put code that relies on data inside another function and call that function from within the callback, passing data to it.

Comment: I have done for now, but its not ideal. Im not sure I can keep it like that. Will try the second method.